# Disable Please visit the Update Network page to update all your sites. Notice from Dashboard

Tags: multisite, wordpress-version

I would like to hide below message you see on dashboard after a WordPress upgrade in Wordpress MU.

I know for hiding version upgrade notice there is one filter as

```
add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_core', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );
```

But I want to disable the following notice

> "Thank you for Updating! Please visit the Update Network page to update all your sites."

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message was fired on two hooks.

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'site_admin_notice' );
add_action( 'network_admin_notices', 'site_admin_notice' );
```

Remove this and you remove the message, use [`remove_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action).

To remove this function use a function, like the follow example.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu','fb_hide_site_notice' );
function fb_hide_site_notice() {
    remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'site_admin_notice' );
}
```

Now for the network ares:

```
add_action( 'network_admin_menu', 'fb_hide_network_notice' );
function fb_hide_network_notice() {
    remove_action( 'network_admin_notices', 'site_admin_notice' );
}
```

Comment: I have tried adding .........remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'site_admin_notice' );
remove_action( 'network_admin_notices', 'site_admin_notice' ); ...........in functions.php of my themes folder.........but with no luck ........I don't want to edit the wordpress core files.

Comment: No, never change the core files. I have update my answer with a example to remove the notice.

Comment: Thanks that worked!!! can't give upvote as am not having enough reputation

Comment: It's still active at the network dashboard.

Comment: Yes, you must also deactivate the hook `network_admin_notices`. I update the answer, now you have the completely source.